# IsChanged Formula not working

Tags: workflow, formula, opportunity

Have what seems like a trivial issue, but it's driving me nuts!

Workflow rule for when a field is edited it should update the Opportunity.Amount.

Workflow:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

Yet when I change the value for Opportunity.Year_1__c it does not update the amount field. There are no formula fields, just a simple field update from a currency field...

Comment: Often I do the most basic mistake to not activate the workflow rule after creating. Hope that's not the case, otherwise try debugging with adding some logs.: [Troubleshooting Workflows with Debug Logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187503&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: Are Year_1__c and the others integers or are they decimals? It looks like you may be trying to populate a currency field with integer values via your formula. As you have it set right now, it only changes with Year 1. If the others are blank or null, do they get evaluated? That could also cause an issue with your formula in how to handle blank or null values.

Comment: Year 1, 2 & 3 are all currency fields. The issue seems to be that if Year 2 or 3 are blank then it doesn't trigger the workflow when Year 1 is changed. But if Year 2 and 3 are $0 then it will work. What's the best way to solve for this?

Comment: Update: I made the default values for those currency fields $0.

Answer (score 2):

Because the currency values were defaulted to blank, it didn't trigger the workflow rule. When I set the default value to 0, it updated the amount field.